# How to access Object in Array NODE JS

Tags: arrays, node.js, object

I have the following JSON data which comes from scraping the technology on a page, I have made a Json array called MyArray that is below:

```
{ url: 'http://www.ozautoelectrics.com',
originalUrl: 'http://www.ozautoelectrics.com',
applications:
[ { name: 'Font Awesome',
   confidence: '100',
   version: '',
   icon: 'Font Awesome.png',
   website: 'http://fontawesome.io',
   categories: [Object] },
 { name: 'Google Analytics',
   confidence: '100',
   version: '',
   icon: 'Google Analytics.svg',
   website: 'http://google.com/analytics',
   categories: [Object] },
 { name: 'jQuery',
   confidence: '100',
   version: '2.1.3',
   icon: 'jQuery.svg',
   website: 'http://jquery.com',
   categories: [Object] } ] }
```

My question is how do I access the [Object] within categories using NODE? or any of the other things inside applications?

I can use myArray.url to get the URL but how do I get whats inside applications properly? I tried myArray.applications.name

Also i'm new.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @user3679330 Any specific reason you have removed my answer as accepted answer?

Comment: I tried to make them all the accepted answer, as they all did what I wanted

Comment: @user3679330  No you can't accept all the answers. you can accept only one that solved you problem. If you accept other answers means it will revert of already accepted answer.

Comment: You can have the accepted answer then, i feel like you wanted it more

Comment: Lol @user3679330 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through applications and use index to access categories.

```js
var myArray = { url: 'http://www.ozautoelectrics.com',
originalUrl: 'http://www.ozautoelectrics.com',
applications:
[ { name: 'Font Awesome',
   confidence: '100',
   version: '',
   icon: 'Font Awesome.png',
   website: 'http://fontawesome.io',
   categories: [Object] },
 { name: 'Google Analytics',
   confidence: '100',
   version: '',
   icon: 'Google Analytics.svg',
   website: 'http://google.com/analytics',
   categories: [Object] },
 { name: 'jQuery',
   confidence: '100',
   version: '2.1.3',
   icon: 'jQuery.svg',
   website: 'http://jquery.com',
   categories: [Object] } ] 
   };
   
   for(var i =0; i<myArray.applications.length;i++){
    console.log(myArray.applications[i].categories);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` method to access each element of array.

```js
var myArray = { 
url: 'http://www.ozautoelectrics.com',
originalUrl: 'http://www.ozautoelectrics.com',
applications: [ { name: 'Font Awesome',
   confidence: '100',
   version: '',
   icon: 'Font Awesome.png',
   website: 'http://fontawesome.io',
   categories: [Object] },
 { name: 'Google Analytics',
   confidence: '100',
   version: '',
   icon: 'Google Analytics.svg',
   website: 'http://google.com/analytics',
   categories: [Object] },
 { name: 'jQuery',
   confidence: '100',
   version: '2.1.3',
   icon: 'jQuery.svg',
   website: 'http://jquery.com',
   categories: [Object] } 
   ]};
   
myArray.applications.forEach(function(value, index, array){
  console.log(value.categories); //Allow to access the array
  //console.log(value.categories[0]); //Allows the first element in the array
});


console.log('Arrow function Solution');
//solution with arrow function
myArray.applications.forEach((value, index, array) => {
  console.log(value.categories); //Allow to access the array
  //console.log(value.categories[0]); //Allows the first element in the array
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash map function for that.
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map

```
var lodash = require('lodash');
var categoriesArr = lodash.map(myArray.applications, (item) => item.categories);
```

Comment: how would you write this without the => ?

Comment: just use regular function, lodash.map(myArray.applications, function(item)  {return item.categories});